# Select same column with different conditions to separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select specific column with different conditions and combine the result in different columns and one result .

I tried something like this , its wrong but to clear the idea

```
Select [ObjectiveKey] as column_1  from [Objectives] where [ID] = 9
union
Select [ObjectiveKey] as column_2 from [Objectives] where [ID] = 12
union
Select [ObjectiveKey] as column_3 from [Objectives] where [ID] = 11
union
Select [ObjectiveKey] as column_4 from [Objectives] where [ID] = 10
union
Select [ObjectiveKey] as column_5 from [Objectives] where [ID] = 32
```

And the result should look like this

[image]

Comment: Please provide some sample data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    column_1 = MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 9 THEN ObjectiveKey END),
    column_2 = MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 12 THEN ObjectiveKey END),
    column_3 = MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 11 THEN ObjectiveKey END),
    column_4 = MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 10 THEN ObjectiveKey END),
    column_5 = MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 32 THEN ObjectiveKey END)
FROM Objectives
WHERE
    ID IN(9, 12, 11, 10, 32)
```

---

As suggested in the comment, you may want to add a filter for `ID`.

Comment: Depending on the size of the table it might still be useful to add the filter `where ID in (9,10,11,12,32)`

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Be sure to check my edit based on @shawnt00 comment.

Comment: Yes I check it and it's gave me the same result

Comment: Yes, it'll give you the same result. The filter is added for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your expected result because it is a graphic, but I think what you need is :

```
Select [ObjectiveKey] as column_1  from [Objectives] where [ID] IN (9,10,11,12,32)
```

Comment: The OP wants to keep columns separate.